# Is there a way to connect two models having same foreign key inside django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-orm

I have 2 models. The models are given. Both of these models use User as foreign key.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    reply_comment = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=path_and_rename)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Now I want to access the profile picture from comment objects inside my django template. I have tried this.

`<img alt="" src="{{comment.author.profile.profile_picture.url}}" class="avatar avatar-120 photo" height="120" width="120"><span`

But it doesn't get the url of the image. I don't understand how can I make a relation between these two models inside the template.

Comment: This is normally correct yes, can you perhaps print every sequence and see where it goes wrong, so: `{{ comment.author }}`, `{{ comment.author.profile }}` and `{{ comment.author.profile.profile_picture }}`

Comment: Problem solved. I don't know what went wrong. I didn't get any url inside src tag by inspect element. Now it got the url. May be it was a session or cache related problem. I have no idea. Thanks @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 1):

The way you did it should work because there is `OneToOne` relationship between `User` and `Profile`.

You should just include the `MEDIA_URL` as a prefix. One way to do it is to add the following property to the `Profile` class:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def get_absolute_image_url(self):
        return "{0}{1}".format(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.profile_picture.url)
```

and then use the property:

```html
<img alt="" src="{{comment.author.profile.get_absolute_image_url}}" class="avatar avatar-120 photo" height="120" width="120">
```